# HAP SelectNodes"[//img]", just pick img nodes with base64 information/understand DocumentNode.SelectNodes

Tags: c#, url, base64, nodes, html-agility-pack

```
            HtmlNodeCollection imgs = new HtmlNodeCollection(doc.DocumentNode);
        imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
            if (imgs != null && imgs.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (HtmlNode img in imgs)
                {
                    HtmlAttribute src = img.Attributes[@"src"];
                    urls.Add(src.Value);

                    {
                    foreach (string Value in urls)

                        { Code for changing Base64 into URL }
```

This is my code for selecting all imgs right now.
But I only want images including base 64 and skip the ones using URL.

I think there could be a solution to already Select only the nodes including it. I first thought SelectNodes just compares the string value, but I seem to be wrong there, because checking for base64 has no results.
I have a regex solution, but I want to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me if anyone runs into the same issue

```
string AttrVal = img.GetAttributeValue("src", null);
if(AttrVal.Contains("base64")
```